# Shifting k times to the left

Tags: scheme, racket

Hi I am trying to implement a program in scheme shifting a list k times to the left.
For example:

```
(shift-k-left ’(1 2 3) 2)
’(3 1 2)
```

I have managed to implement a code that do shift left once here:

```
(define shift-left
 (lambda (ls)
   (if (null? ls)
    '()
     (append (cdr ls)
          (cons (car ls)
                '())))))
```

I want to use shift left as a function on shift-k-left.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using circular-list from srfi/1.

```
  (require srfi/1)

  (define (shift xs k)
      (define n (length xs))
      (take (drop (apply circular-list xs) k) n))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your `shift-left` to shift `k` times:

- If `k` is 0: do nothing
- If `k` is not 0: shift `k-1` times, and then `shift-left` the result.

That is,

```
(define (shift-left-k ls k)
    (if (= k 0)
        ls
        (shift-left (shift-left-k ls (- k 1)))))
```

You may want to adjust to do something sensible for negative `k`.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to count down `n` while `cons`ing the `car`s of `r` to `p` and the `cdr`s to `r` then the base case becomes append `r` to the reverse of `p`. If we run into a `null?` `r` we `reverse` `p` and continue this wraps the rotation:

```
(define (shift-k-left l n)
  ; assume that n >= 0
  (let loop ((n n) (p '()) (r l))   
    (if (= n 0)
        (append r (reverse p))
        (if (null? r)
            (loop n '() (reverse p))
            (loop (- n 1) (cons (car r) p) (cdr r))))))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is something similar:

```
(define (addn value n)
  (let loop ((value value) (n n))
    (if (zero? n)
        value
        (loop (add1 value) (- n 1)))))

(addn 5 3)
; ==> 8
```

Now you could make an abstraction:

```
(define (repeat proc)
  (lambda (v n)
    ...))
(define addn (repeat add1))

(addn 5 3)
; ==> 8

(define shift-k-left (repeat shift-left))
(shift-k-left ’(1 2 3) 2)
; ==> (3 1 2)
```

Needless to say `repeat` looks a lot like `add1` does.

NB: The naming is off. Your implementation is more "rotate" than "shift". 
`shift-left` is actually more like `cdr` than your implemenation.